# How do I explicitely identify how many monitors are supported by integrated graphics?

Tags: multiple-monitors, cpu

## Integrated Graphics Support

### How do I get explicit information?

I am trying to determine if and if yes, how many, any given integrated graphics chip supports extending the desktop over multiple displays, without the presence of a discrete GPU.

In effect, which CPUs with integrated graphics can support multiple displays, and how many displays can I extend a desktop over?

### Research I have done

I have tried three different search terms here, and checked the first four pages by both relevancy and date, newest first. *No questions were either current or relevant, or answered*

I have searched the internet with a few terms. I looked through a set of returned pages, including pages from Intel and AMD.

#### What I found

Intel has a few undated pages listing a set of Intel Graphics Controllers and chip sets which support three independent displays.

AMD has pages about setting up multiple displays with specific technologies, but it is not stated if this technology is present in AMD integrated graphics on their desktop CPUs. Specifications I found for some of their CPUs state they support a display port. These specifications do not state which standards or explicitly state how many displays are supported.

#### Saturated by irrelevant information

Search results are mostly about GPUs that support multiple displays. This is not relevant, because it isn't integrated graphics on CPUs.

Search results from the AMD domain for integrated graphics supporting multiple displays are for an integrated graphics product, and not integrated graphics on CPUs.

Other results lead to displays, information about splitters, hubs, docking stations, and USB C.

### What information I need which isn't answered

How many independent displays a CPU can support without a GPU, using only integrated graphics.

### What I want answered

How do I look up this specification for individual chips?
For example, what specification do I need to explicitly look for?
And where can I find a list of CPUs by supported number of displays?

### Please keep in mind

- I know about daisy chaining monitors.
- I know a discrete GPU can support multiple monitors.
- I know a GPU used to be required to do so.
- Technology has advanced, and my information is likely dated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Putting your "I want answered" question to Google: Intel [up to 4](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/how-many-displays-can-uhd730-or-uhd770-support/td-p/1350844), [Intel instructions how to set up 3 on 3rd Gen and newer])(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025671/graphics.html); [AMD 5600G 3](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/pci9lx/amd_5600g_how_many_displays_does_it_support/)...

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the comment. I am well aware of these results, but I need to be able to find the information explicitly stated by chip, for any chip.

Comment: Sorry, friend, but I'm afraid you're looking for a table nobody has ever compiled. The 2 provided answers are probably the best ones available. I hope someone can rip the info out of AMD like @rickhg12hs just did for Intel.

Comment: While a table would be nice, key words on specification standards, or just generally how PC builders determine what can be supported would be useful.

Comment: You're not now talking about PC builders, but chip manufacturers. I'm betting the "how" is something strictly confidential. As the question about iGPU support, it's about internal design of the CPU. Standards don't apply there, only in how it communicates with the outside world. And even then only for compatibility reasons - nothing prevents a manufacturer from deciding their CPU can only be used with a mobo of their own design. Which reminds me, while researching this I saw it mentioned that even if the iGPU can run 4 monitors, the mobo can also have limitations.

Comment: Nice of Intel to produce such a detailed comparison chart. [This](https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors) is the only comparable thing I've found from AMD. That lists "graphics core count" which I interpret as the number of iGPU cores, but that's hardly the same as number of supported displays, methinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial (only 400 CPUs), and crude, attempt to get some Intel® processor capabilities by exporting the Intel Processor Specifications Comparison from the [webpage](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=232167,233092,233091,233093,232909,232163,232105,232136,233459,233391,232169,232151,231806,231805,233389,232126,232157,232173,232132,232127,233392,232134,233458,232156,232108,232107,232103,232133,232160,232130,232101,233390,232168,232128,232166,232131,232175,232164,232161,232099,232135,232171,232162,232172,232138,231803,231804,233089,233090,233393,230380,230379,230575,230579,232143,232153,230495,232148,230577,230580,232147,230578,230574,232145,232152,232154,230573,232155,232141,230490,230492,232139,232146,232150,230499,232144,230498,232149,232142,230493,230500,230496,230903,230902,219491,230901,230900,229976,229975,230904,230905,228459,229953,228794,228438,228795,226058,228442,228441,228439,225916,227849,227851,227852,227854,227850,227853,132217,226450,226264,226451,226263,226269,226257,226453,226261,226266,132221,226452,226260,226256,226454,226259,226254,226455,226258,226255,226253,226449,226262,226265,96163,96170,96164,96169,223097,223095,223096,223094,96142,96156,96158,96150,226066,226059,226055,219435,196311,219436,196312,134584,132225,132224,132226,134586,132222,96144,96143,96141,96140,96149,134591,132219,132228,134596,132216,134597,132212,132214,132215,134601,132211,134589,134594,134599,212255,212257,212260,212262,214806,214805,217370,217371,217369,217379,217375,217378,217377,217376,217368,217367,213802,217183,217182,217185,217184,217187,217181,213806,213803,213805,213804,213799,213801,213798,213800,213797,213796,212263,212264,212265,212266,212267,212268,212269,201894,201890,201893,201898,201889,201891,212270,212273,212277,212272,212274,212275,212278,212279,212047,212251,212252,212325,212256,201901,201900,201902,201903,201904,214758,214754,213356,213357,212326,212324,212329,212328,208659,212330,212327,196656,208660,196655,197384,208663,201905,208646,208072,208667,205686,207905,207902,207908,207901,207907,207899,207900,207909,207898,208079,208074,209736,208656,209735,208081,208078,208076,208082,207903,207906,208018,208651,208920,208652,208657,208658,208922,208661,208662,208921,208664,208016,201899,201886,201887,205904,203904,203905,203903,203907,197889,201892,201896,201888,203682,201908,201909,199274,203892,199340,203895,199339,199338,199337,199336,199341,196594,196593,199268,203897,203890,199290,199283,203898,199284,203899,199281,199282,199280,203893,203891,199311,199279,199316,203908,199335,199314,203906,199328,203902,199332,199324,203901,199288,203896,199289,203894,199287,199286,199285,199270,199271,199276,199277,199275,199273,201839,201895,201837,201897,202329,201838,197307,197305,197310,197309,197304,197308,197890,198389,197888,196451,196455,195436,196454,196449,196452,196448,197122,197123,196588,196603,196591,196592,197120,196597,195253,191067,192996,193565,193560,194374,194375,194376,193559,193554,193741,193744,193742,193748).  You can select product families, some capabilities, etc., for comparison.

```python
import polars as pl
from io import StringIO

lines = []
with open("Intel_ARK_ComparisonChart_2023_03_01.csv", "r") as f:
    while (line := f.readline()):
        if "," in line:  # Intel put various headers to mess up csv
            lines.append(line)

csv = StringIO("".join(lines))
df = pl.read_csv(csv)

mini_df = df.filter(pl.col(" ").str.contains("(?i)processor number|display")).transpose()
mini_df.columns = mini_df.row(0)
mini_df = mini_df[1:]

pl.cfg.Config.set_tbl_rows(-1)

print(mini_df)
```

And here's the output:

```
shape: (400, 2)
┌──────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ Processor Number ┆ # of Displays Supported ‡ │
│ ---              ┆ ---                       │
│ str              ┆ str                       │
╞══════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ i9-12900TE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900E        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900HK       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700TE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1270PE        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700E        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1240P         ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-12450H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12100TE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12100E        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12300HE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12100         ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-12400         ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-12600K        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700         ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700K        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700T        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900         ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900K        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900T        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-8257U         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-8557U         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-8665UE        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-8365UE        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-8145UE        ┆ 3                         │
│ 4305UE           ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2254ME         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2276ME         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2254ML         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2276ML         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-9100E         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-9100HL        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-9100TE        ┆ 3                         │
│ N4200E           ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10210U        ┆ 3                         │
│ G7400E           ┆ 4                         │
│ G7400TE          ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-10710U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10510U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10110U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10510Y        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10210Y        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10110Y        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-1005G1        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1035G4        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1035G7        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-1068NG7       ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1038NG7       ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-1065G7        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1035G1        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-11370H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-11300H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1060G7        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-1000G1        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-1000G4        ┆ 3                         │
│ J5040            ┆ 3                         │
│ J4125            ┆ 3                         │
│ J4025            ┆ 3                         │
│ N5030            ┆ 3                         │
│ N4120            ┆ 3                         │
│ N4020            ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-11375H        ┆ 4                         │
│ 6405U            ┆ 3                         │
│ 5305U            ┆ 3                         │
│ 5205U            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-8260U         ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900            ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900T           ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10400         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10600         ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250           ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10400T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10600T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10320         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10300         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10300T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100T        ┆ 3                         │
│ G6600            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6500T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G6500            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G5920            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10600K        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700         ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900         ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900K        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700K        ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290T          ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10750H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10980HK       ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10300H        ┆ 3                         │
│ G5905T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G5925            ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10810U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10325         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10105T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10505         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10310U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10305         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10105         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10400H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10610U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10850H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10305T        ┆ 3                         │
│ G5905            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6405T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G6405            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6505            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6505T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G6605            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500H        ┆ 3                         │
│ W-10855M         ┆ 3                         │
│ W-10885M         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10875H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10885H        ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900TE          ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250E          ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500E        ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400TE          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250TE         ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400E           ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900E           ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100E        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900E        ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290E          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270E          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270TE         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290TE         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700E        ┆ 3                         │
│ 6805             ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10850K        ┆ 3                         │
│ N6211            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6425RE           ┆ 3                         │
│ 6427FE           ┆ 3                         │
│ 6414RE           ┆ 3                         │
│ 6212RE           ┆ 3                         │
│ J6426            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6211E            ┆ 3                         │
│ N6415            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6425E            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6413E            ┆ 3                         │
│ J6413            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10200H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10870H        ┆ 3                         │
│ 6305E            ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115GRE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1185G7E       ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1145GRE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115G4E       ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1145G7E       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1185GRE       ┆ 4                         │
│ 6305             ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1110G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1125G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1130G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1135G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1140G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1145G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1160G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1165G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1180G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1185G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ 7505             ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1165G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1135G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1125G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1120G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-11700K        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-11700T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-11900         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2324G          ┆ 1                         │
│ i9-11900T        ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2356G          ┆ 1                         │
│ E-2374G          ┆ 1                         │
│ E-2378G          ┆ 1                         │
│ W-1350           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1350P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1370           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1370P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1390           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1390P          ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-12900TE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900E        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900HK       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700TE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1270PE        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700E        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1240P         ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-12450H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12100TE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12100E        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12300HE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-12100         ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-12400         ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-12600K        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700         ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700K        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-12700T        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900         ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900K        ┆ 4                         │
│ i9-12900T        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-8257U         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-8557U         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-8665UE        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-8365UE        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-8145UE        ┆ 3                         │
│ 4305UE           ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2254ME         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2276ME         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2254ML         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2276ML         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-9100E         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-9100HL        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-9100TE        ┆ 3                         │
│ N4200E           ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10210U        ┆ 3                         │
│ G7400E           ┆ 4                         │
│ G7400TE          ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-10710U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10510U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10110U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10510Y        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10210Y        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10110Y        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-1005G1        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1035G4        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1035G7        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-1068NG7       ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1038NG7       ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-1065G7        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-1035G1        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-11370H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-11300H        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1060G7        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-1000G1        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-1000G4        ┆ 3                         │
│ J5040            ┆ 3                         │
│ J4125            ┆ 3                         │
│ J4025            ┆ 3                         │
│ N5030            ┆ 3                         │
│ N4120            ┆ 3                         │
│ N4020            ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-11375H        ┆ 4                         │
│ 6405U            ┆ 3                         │
│ 5305U            ┆ 3                         │
│ 5205U            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-8260U         ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900            ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900T           ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10400         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10600         ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250           ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10400T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10600T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10320         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10300         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10300T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100T        ┆ 3                         │
│ G6600            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6500T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G6500            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G5920            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10600K        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700         ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900         ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900K        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700K        ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290T          ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10750H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10980HK       ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10300H        ┆ 3                         │
│ G5905T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G5925            ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10810U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10325         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10105T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10505         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10310U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10305         ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10105         ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10400H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10610U        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10850H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10305T        ┆ 3                         │
│ G5905            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6405T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G6405            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6505            ┆ 3                         │
│ G6505T           ┆ 3                         │
│ G6605            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500H        ┆ 3                         │
│ W-10855M         ┆ 3                         │
│ W-10885M         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10875H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10885H        ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900TE          ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250E          ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10500E        ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400TE          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1250TE         ┆ 3                         │
│ G6400E           ┆ 3                         │
│ G5900E           ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100E        ┆ 3                         │
│ i3-10100TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10900E        ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290E          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270E          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1270TE         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700TE       ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1290TE         ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10700E        ┆ 3                         │
│ 6805             ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-10850K        ┆ 3                         │
│ N6211            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6425RE           ┆ 3                         │
│ 6427FE           ┆ 3                         │
│ 6414RE           ┆ 3                         │
│ 6212RE           ┆ 3                         │
│ J6426            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6211E            ┆ 3                         │
│ N6415            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6425E            ┆ 3                         │
│ 6413E            ┆ 3                         │
│ J6413            ┆ 3                         │
│ i5-10200H        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-10870H        ┆ 3                         │
│ 6305E            ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115GRE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1185G7E       ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1145GRE       ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115G4E       ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1145G7E       ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1185GRE       ┆ 4                         │
│ 6305             ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1110G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1125G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1130G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1135G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1140G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1145G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1160G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1165G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1180G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1185G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ 7505             ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1115G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-1165G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i5-1135G7        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1125G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i3-1120G4        ┆ 4                         │
│ i7-11700K        ┆ 3                         │
│ i7-11700T        ┆ 3                         │
│ i9-11900         ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2324G          ┆ 1                         │
│ i9-11900T        ┆ 3                         │
│ E-2356G          ┆ 1                         │
│ E-2374G          ┆ 1                         │
│ E-2378G          ┆ 1                         │
│ W-1350           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1350P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1370           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1370P          ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1390           ┆ 3                         │
│ W-1390P          ┆ 3                         │
└──────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I am going to award this as the answer, until someone provides the same level of information for both Intel and AMD, and even then, it is going to have a run for its money. Your solution is brilliant, and I hope you can do the same for AMD. This is possible the best answer I have ever seen in novelty, creativity and elegance.
What is your code written in?

Comment: The code is in Python, using the [`polars`](https://www.pola.rs/) package (and `rust` under-the-hood - you don't need to know `rust` to use the Python package).  I just happened to notice that Intel's _processor comparison_ webpage had the parameter you were looking for and that they had a CSV download of the table (although, Intel could have formatted it better).  The code just cut's out the info you were looking for.  I didn't see the same level of detail at the AMD comparison webpage, but I did notice that some AMD webpages could be _"scaped"_ to get the URL of the detailed detailed specs.

Comment: So, you could get the same info from AMD by _"scraping"_ some webpages to get a list of URLs, and then _"scrape"_ those pages to get the info you want.  The code to do that wouldn't be long, but figuring out the exact sequence of _"scraping"_ and formatting may take a while.  If you have any coder friends, tell them about the webpage scraping and that you know _"It's impossible!  It can't be done!"_ ... and then watch them do it.  :-)

Comment: You should also know that Intel has many more CPUs than the list of 400 that I got.  Intel's comparison webpage began to have some problems if I selected too many CPUs.  After failing to get _"all"_ the CPUs, I backed off to 400 so that it was possible to download the CSV.

Comment: Also, regarding some of the Intel CPUs, I noticed that some mentioned that it _"... supports 4 independent displays, but only 3 can be active at any one time..."_ I'm not sure if that info is important to you, and it also wasn't clear in the comparison table which CPUs that _caution_ applied to.

Comment: I would like to know, if you think it is possible to scrape the tech specs for monitors from samsung the same way. I need monitors that can be daisy chained, and having trouble making sure there is a DP-out port

Comment: @PeterSmedskjaer IDK, maybe.  I don't know enough about monitors to evaluate _"monitors that can be daisy chained"_.  Is there a specific tech spec that determines that?  Perhaps if you ask a new question showing the URLs, etc., of the monitors with/without the required feature, a _scraping strategy_ could be made.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anyone compile a list of CPUs by supported number
of displays, and I don't think that it exists.
The number of all the possible variants for every CPU version and
sub-version is just too enormous.

You will need to look for the specification-page for each CPU that you're
considering, in order to find the number of supported displays.

For example, the Intel article
[What is the Maximum Number of Displays that My Intel® Graphics Can Support?](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000029126/graphics.html)

> - [Identify the processor model](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006059/processors.html).
> - Go to [Product Page Support](https://ark.intel.com/).
> - Locate the search field on the top right corner of the page and type in the number of your Intel® Processor.
> - On the product specification page and under Essential, locate Processor Graphics.
> - Under Processor Graphics, check the # of Displays Supported.

The field to search for in Intel seems to be "# of Displays Supported".

You may also use Google to search, for example, for one random CPU:
`"i7-1280P" "# of Displays Supported"`